# Copy/paste intermittently doesn't work on Ubuntu and macOS but fine on Windows 10, ideas on what could cause?

Tags: windows-10, macos, ubuntu, usb, copy-paste

I have a computer where I dual boot the newest version of Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Windows 10. I also have a work laptop Apple MacBook that's fairly new with M1 chip. The issue I'm facing is inconsistent copy/paste functionality on all these systems but Windows 10.

When I press the respective <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> | <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or even highlighting text with mouse and right clicking mouse to copy or then pasting. What happens is many times the copied data does not enter my clipboard. So when I paste the content is the prior thing I copied. Not the current. This happens on both macOS and Ubuntu. It does not happen on Windows 10.

Ubuntu and Windows 10 are running on same PC. Laptop Macbook is of course its own device.

In diagnosing this I first thought the problem was limited to my Apple MacBook laptop. This caused me to try and clear caches and even create a new user profile. It eventually lead me to replace the mouse with a new one. I then started to notice the issue also on Ubuntu dual boot pc.

The mouse and keyboard at first were connected through my monitors USB hub. It has a built in KVM that allows me to switch between laptop (MacBook) and PC. I then thought maybe the monitor was going bad so I removed all usb connection to monitor and now use a standalone usb switch with a button to go back and forth. This is a USB switch I used for a decade before I got new monitor and always worked fine. But still same issue. Both this standalone usb switch and monitors KVM switch also worked 100% fine with Windows 10 on the dual boot PC, but not with Ubuntu.

I've tried upgrading all packages as far as they can go. I've tried ruling out certain apps. But it's not limited to a specific text editor or web browser. The real odd thing is it all works fine on Windows 10. The only difference with Windows 10 is I don't install my development dotfiles onto it. Things like my vimrc and bashrc and other dot files.

I scanned MacBook laptop with MalwareBytes and it was clear.

I'm just out of ideas. Does anybody have any others?